# C#.NET IntPtr Invalid Type

Tags: c#, intptr

```
private string getLngLat(string strLAC, string strCID)
    {
        string str;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest length = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://www.google.com/glm/mmap"));
            length.Method = "POST";
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(strLAC);
            byte[] numArray = AjaxFrm.PostData(num, Convert.ToInt32(strCID));
            length.ContentLength = (long)((int)numArray.Length);
            length.ContentType = "application/binary";
            length.GetRequestStream().Write(numArray, 0, (int)numArray.Length);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)length.GetResponse();
            byte[] numArray1 = new byte[checked((IntPtr)response.ContentLength)]; // ERROR AT HERE
            response.GetResponseStream().Read(numArray1, 0, (int)numArray1.Length);
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                str = string.Format("Error {0}", response.StatusCode);
            }
            else
            {
                byte num1 = numArray1[0];
                byte num2 = numArray1[1];
                byte num3 = numArray1[2];
                if ((numArray1[3] << 24 | numArray1[4] << 16 | numArray1[5] << 8 | numArray1[6]) != 0)
                {
                    str = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    double num4 = (double)(numArray1[7] << 24 | numArray1[8] << 16 | numArray1[9] << 8 | numArray1[10]) / 1000000;
                    double num5 = (double)(numArray1[11] << 24 | numArray1[12] << 16 | numArray1[13] << 8 | numArray1[14]) / 1000000;
                    str = string.Format("{0}&{1}", num5, num4);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            str = string.Format("Error {0}", exception.Message);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

`byte[] numArray1 = new byte[checked((IntPtr)response.ContentLength)];`

here i get the error with

`Error  3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IntPtr' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

How come will get this error? how to solve it?

Comment: [`IntPtr.ToInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.intptr.toint32.aspx)?

Comment: You sure you don't mean `long`? This makes my eyes bleed btw.

Comment: Why are you casting `ContentLength` to an `IntPtr` in the first place?

Comment: you should post your code for the `checked()` function maybe there are  the problem

Comment: @WiiMaxx: `checked` isn't a function - it's a keyword in C# to use checked arithmetic and conversions.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right, this is the `checked` definition http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the array length directly, there's no need to attempt to convert to `IntPtr` first:

```
byte[] numArray1 = new byte[response.ContentLength];
```

`IntPtr` is a type only intended to hold pointer values, so the usual rules for integral types don't apply. A pointer value is not a sensible array length, so the language designers did not permit using `IntPtr` to specify an array length.

Comment: u missed the `checked` ?

Comment: @ChinYe The `checked` does not add anything here, but if you believe otherwise, please edit your question to clarify why you think you need it and I'll edit my answer to address that point.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim was to convert to an `int`, you just need to do that instead:

```
byte[] numArray1 = new byte[checked((int)response.ContentLength)];
```

That will avoid you trying to allocate more than 2GB for `numArray1`. You don't need to do this from a *compiler* perspective though - you can allocate an array using a `long` value for the length. It's just that it will fall over at execution time if the size is large enough. (In .NET 4.5 you can use an application configuration setting to allow for arrays with a total size of more than 2GB, but I'm not sure offhand whether that allows for the number of *elements* to exceed `int.MaxValue`.)

So actually, you'd be better off with just leaving the checking to the CLR:

```
byte[] numArray1 = new byte[response.ContentLength];
```

... or if you *do* want to impose some maximum size, do that explicitly. (I'd suggest a maximum of less than 2GB, too...)

You should also consider the possibility of `ContentLength` being -1, indicating that the client hasn't specified it in a response header.